# which is faster ? NSXMLParser or KissXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsxml

HI,

i need a XML parser. i want to know that which one is faster? NSXMLParser or KissXML ?

looking forward for replies...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good link regarding this question: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project.

Answer (score 0):

How much XML are you going to parse? If it is less than a few dozen kilobytes then the difference is probably milliseconds. What kind of XML are you parsing?